# Example for gephi-toolkit 0.9.0

Tags: toolkit, gephi

Gephi toolkit 0.8.7 comes with some nice examples, but for a reason I have to use nightly build (0.9.0-SNAPSHOT) and these demo examples won't work on this version of gephi toolkit. Is there any chance I could get a working example for this version? Or any clues on how to make things work?

The main problem is "PApplet", which is no longer in use.

**The old way: (toolkit 0.8.7)**

```
ProcessingTarget target = (ProcessingTarget) previewController.getRenderTarget(RenderTarget.PROCESSING_TARGET); 
PApplet applet = target.getApplet(); 
applet.init();
```

**The new way: (toolkit 0.9.0)**

```
G2DTarget target = (G2DTarget) previewController.getRenderTarget(RenderTarget.G2D_TARGET); 
??? = target.getGraphics();
```

What is there to substitute it?
I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See the updated examples at [Gephi toolkit demos](https://github.com/gephi/gephi-toolkit-demos/blob/master/src/main/java/org/gephi/toolkit/demos/PreviewJFrame.java) 0.9.1, they helped me with the same issue.

Gephi now uses a different rendering model and the Toolkit does not provide a component for rendering (and event handling). Following code was taken from Toolkit demos:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(target.getImage(), 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
}
```

For more information check out the demo [PreviewSketch](https://github.com/gephi/gephi-toolkit-demos/blob/master/src/main/java/org/gephi/toolkit/demos/plugins/preview/PreviewSketch.java) class.